# One folder inside OneDrive folder not accessible in Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, permissions

I have a problem with accessing the "Documents" folder inside OneDrive folder on a Windows partition. I have set up dual boot with two partitions. One is Windows partition that contains OneDrive folder (inside my user folder) another is the Ubuntu partition. I have set that the OneDrive folder is not "on demand", but still cannot access the "Documents" folder inside OneDrive folder. Other folders and files inside OneDrive folder are accessible in Ubuntu, only the Documents folder is not accessible. It looks like the Documents folder is set to "on demand" access, but I can not find any setting to unset this (if this is even possible).

Other solutions only mention to uncheck "on deman" option for the entire OneDrive folder and I have already done this. But there is no mention of my specific problem.